# Integral and derivative of $\lfloor x\rfloor$ and $x - \lfloor x\rfloor$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I've always assumed by graphical inspection that

$\int (x - \lfloor x\rfloor)\mathrm dx = \dfrac{(x - \lfloor x\rfloor)^2 + \lfloor x\rfloor}{2}$ ([W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28x+-+floor%28x%29%29%5E2+%2B+floor%28x%29%29%2F2)) and

$\int \lfloor x\rfloor\mathrm dx = x\lfloor x\rfloor - \dfrac{\lfloor x\rfloor(\lfloor x\rfloor + 1)}{2}$ ([W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2afloor%28x%29+-+.5floor%28x%29%28floor%28x%29+%2B+1%29))

Why does Wolfram|Alpha say for each integral, "[no result found in terms of standard mathematical functions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+floor%28x%29)"?

I also assumed that $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \lfloor x \rfloor = 0$, yet according to Wolfram|Alpha $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \lfloor x \rfloor = \mathop {\rm floor}'(x)$—which is not not explained, but the graph looks [very strange](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+d%2Fdx+floor%28x%29+from+-1.3+to+1.3).  What is going on here?

Comment: Because, there are some functions which are difficult to integrate. For example take $f(x)=\sqrt{\sin{x}}$ you can't find an anti-derivative for this function. The best you can do is to approximate this function by using $\text{Simpson's 1/3 rule}$ but for using that you need your integral to be a definite integral.

Comment: @Chandr: actually, there is a closed form for the integral of $\sqrt{\sin\,x}$, but I won't get into that here. But properly integrating the floor and fractional part functions is not so straightforward, I agree.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33547) is an apropos thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me start with the last question. $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is a piece-wise constant. It's is not differentiable at $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, which is why W|A gives `Floor'[x]` for an answer. `Floor'[x]` is a short form for `Derivative[1][Floor][x]`, i.e. derivative remains unevaluated in agreement with *Mathematica*'s evaluation principles.

When W|A says integral can not expressed in terms of known function, it means that `Integrate` could not provide a solution for your integral.

The expressions you wrote are correct for a definite integral, i.e.
$$
  \int_0^x \left( y - \lfloor y \rfloor \right) \mathrm{d} y = \frac{1}{2} \left( \left( x - \lfloor x \rfloor \right)^2 + \lfloor x \rfloor \right)
$$
in doing so you completely fixed an additive piece-wise constant, ortherwise you should write $ \int \left( x - \lfloor x \rfloor \right) \mathrm{d} x = \frac{x^2}{2} - x \lfloor x \rfloor + C$.

Comment: Also: Floor'[x] may mean a certain distribution, which is zero except at integers, and has delta-function properties at the integers.  We need this to recover Floor[x] by integrating it.