# Indefinite integral from floor of $x$

Tags: calculus, integration, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I want to calculate $\displaystyle \int [x] dx$ where $[]$ is floor function.

I don't know if it is just $kx+C$ for $x \in [k, k+1)$ and $(k+1)x+C$ for $x =k+1$ or I'm missing something

Comment: There is an indefinite integral, described here
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33547/is-this-a-justified-expression-for-the-integral-of-the-floor-function

Answer (score -1):

$$ \int _0^y [x] dx = \sum _{i=0}^{[y]-1} i + [y] \int _{[y]}^y dx $$

$$ = \frac 12 [y]([y]-1) + [y](y-[y])  $$

Comment: Looks to me like we both derived identical expressions using different methods.