# Integral of greatest integer function.

Tags: indefinite-integrals

$[x]$ denotes the greatest integer $\leq x$. Let $f(x)=[x]$

What is the indefinite integral (without limits) of $f(x)$ ?

And if $f(x) = e^{-7[x]}$ what would the indefinite integral be?

Comment: $[x]$ can be thought of as a sum of step functions, so the integral will likely be a sum of ever-increasing ramp functions.

Comment: As-is, this function cannot have an antiderivative as a consequence of Darboux's theorem, because $[x]$ does not satisfy the intermediate value property (see below).  What you want can only be done if we restrict $f$ to the points $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$, and in this case the antiderivative would be defined piecewise.  As Guilherme says, it will look like a union of lines with different slopes.  Think about what the derivative of $\text{abs}(x)$ will look like for $x \neq 0$ to get some intuition. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)

Comment: Lots of possibly relevant questions and answers if you search this site for the title of your question.

Comment: @KajHansen then how did one came to a result  like the one below?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1312213/indefinite-integral-of-floor-function-integration-by-substitution

Comment: I found this `[link] https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33547/is-this-a-justified-expression-for-the-integral-of-the-floor-function/33568#33568`. In the answer of the thread in the link, does anyone one knows how did he get the $\\{x\\}\lfloor x\rfloor$ part? Or should I open another thread just to ask this?

Answer (score 2):

$\int[x]~dx=x[x]-\dfrac{[x]([x]+1)}{2}+C$

Comment: Why is the integral different than the one posted here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33547/is-this-a-justified-expression-for-the-integral-of-the-floor-function/33568#33568